# how to use VueJs components in Django using django webpack loader?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-webpack-loader

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/michaelbukachi/django-vuejs-tutorial/wiki/Django-Vue.js-Integration-Tutorial) and integrated Django and VueJs using django-webpack-loader, now the main.js output from django-webpack-loader is loading to my index.html

This is my project directory structure

```
 - assets
  - bundles
     - app.js
  - js
     - components
           - Demo.vue
     - index.js
 - db.sqlite3
 - manage.py
 - myapp
 - myproject
 - node_modules
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
 - requirements.txt
 - templates
 - webpack.config.js
 - webpack-stats.json
```

My `Demo.vue` component has been imported to the `index.js` and using `webpack.config.js` file all necessary file has been bundled together to `app.js`.

My question is what is the next step? For example, if I have some VueJs components and want to use them in some of my templates how should I do that? Should I create components in the component directory and bundle them all? If this is the case how should I choose to use or not use a component in a specific template? And how should I use Django template tags to insert dynamic data? Or I should write my components in another way?

I know there is multiple questions here, but I couldn't find a good reference to answer my questions so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it's helpful, here's one of my live production Django apps: https://github.com/wcarhart/willcarh.art. It doesn't use Vue.js, but it does use vanilla JS on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Django uses a templating language, called [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/), to pass context (information) from view to template. Assuming that `myapp` is a Django app, you should have a `myapp/views.py` file by default.

In `myapp/views.py`, you have the ability to create a *view* (code that is run when a specific URL is accessed). For example, your view could look something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    context = {
        'my_variable': 'my_variable_value',
    }
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

Then, in `template.html`*, you can use Jinja to parse your context (access `my_variable`'s value). Your template doesn't have to be an HTML file, it can be anything (JS, PHP, etc.), it's just the template file that's loaded from your view.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ my_variable }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can use Jinja with Javascript too:

```
<script>
function test() {
    console.log({{ my_variable }});
}
</script>
```

Jinja supports a variety of functionality, including loops, if blocks, and custom functions (tags). Read more: https://codeburst.io/jinja-2-explained-in-5-minutes-88548486834e

If you're using static files that are *NOT* in your template file, you'll have to serve them as [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/). This is a little more complicated, but not hard! You'll have to use a third party library for serving these files in production, like [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/). [Here's a great tutorial for Django static files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ETQf3TQ9gc), as this extends past the scope of this question.

**Best practice is to make a directory `myapp/templates` and put `template.html` in that directory. Then, point Django to your `templates` folder in `settings.py`:*

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["myapp/templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I am well aware that how django template works, I should have mentioned that, I just don't know how to use components? for example  imagine If I have an avatar component and the avatar component loads to the  template from bundle output from webpack-loader(main.js in this case), how should pass the avatar source image path(the django variable) to the avatar component,

Comment: @salmanrezaie I may be misunderstanding your question, but if you have your Vue component in `index.js`, you can specify `index.js` as a template in Django and then use Jinja to pass Django context variables into the template. As for passing JSON, I usually pass JSON between Django models as a string, and then parse them in Python before passing them to a view. This could work for Vue, but there's probably a better way

Comment: small correction: while you _can_ use jinja2, django has its own template language.